# YAMLFORM Element Settings

Tags: forms, 8

I'm using [yamlform](https://www.drupal.org/project/yamlform) in my Drupal 8 site and I want to add a new setting **(i.e General Settings, Form Display etc)** to each of my fields based on if I have a handler attached to my form.

I have used the

```
function prepare()
```

method for this in my custom elements, but I would like to add it to all existing elements as well, there are several hooks available but I'm not sure which one would be ***most appropriate.***

I realise that yamlform gives you a custom settings box, but I need something a bit more obvious for my non-tech end users.

Thanks.

Comment: Right now, you might have to use hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() to add custom settings to the YAML Form module's UI.  You are able to add custom classes to an element. What is the exact setting are you looking to add to an element?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yeah I ended up using hook_form_alter in the end, I'll add and answer detailing my steps, thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

So In the end I had to use hook_form_alter, here's a quick trimmed down example of how I achieved my particular problem:

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

if ($form_state->getFormObject() instanceof YamlFormUiElementEditForm and hashandler) {

$form['newsection'] = [
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => t('New Section'),
];
$form['newsection']['newfield'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('New field'),
];
```